# how to use true and false statement in a binded class using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have multiple errors if a user inputs the wrong details. I'm trying to change the border color to red if the error returns true and no border color if it returns false.

This is my code-

```
<Datepicker
  :class="{
  'form-error-outline':v$.allActivityPeriods.$each.$response.$errors[
  index
  ].from.length > 0
  }"/>
```

how do I add true or false statements to my bonded class?

Comment: Can't see any problem, it should work as it is. Maybe you can provide some more information. One tip to shorten the syntax is - `:class="{
'form-error-outline':v$.allActivityPeriods.$each.$response.$errors[index].from.length}"`

Answer (score 1):

Classes are conditionally added if the expression on the right-hand side evaluates to `true`. So if `v$.allActivityPeriods.$each.$response.$errors[index].from.length > 0` equals `true` then the `form-error-outline` class will be applied to the element.

It looks like some deeply nested state, and I don’t know what that root `v$` variable is. But you should have some sort of property (computed or otherwise) in your component itself that you can access and check:

```html
<DatePicker
    :class="{ 'form-error-outline': hasErrors['field_name'] }"
/>
```

```js
export default {
  computed() {
    hasErrors(field) {
      return field in this.errors && this.errors[field].length > 0;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following with an array syntax for the class and using ternary operators to check for conditions

```
<Datepicker
        :class=“[v$.allActivityPeriods.$each.$response.$errors[index].from.length > 0 ?
  'form-error-outline': 
 'regular style', 
'more unconditional styles here'
]”
```